# c# Upload local file to Server using FTP. The c# files are on hosted on the server

Tags: c#, server

My ASP.NET website is hosted in a Shared Windows Hosting server.   I'm trying to upload files from the local drive to server folder.   I had gone through many examples available.  They are able to upload when the application is hosted locally.  But when the same application is hosted on the remote server it is not working.

I'm able to accomplish this using PHP, but did not find a proper script using c#.

Please help.

Regards
Mohan Kumar VS

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're facing?  The description sounds like you're just FTP-ing code files to a server.  Is the code itself broken in some way?  What isn't working?

Comment: Since you're on a shared windows server, your provider will most likely tell you your physical path location (ie: d:\yourapp\files). Just use the FileUpload class... Not sure why you're trying to FTP from the page (unless I'm missing something) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks... Got it sorted out.. It was folder permission issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This code is coped from working solution.

> ```
> <add key="ServerReportFTP" value="ftp://10.1.1.1"/>
> <add key="ServerReportFTPUserName" value="username"/>
> <add key="ServerReportFTPPassword" value="password"/>
> ```

```
private static void UploadFileToFtp(string sourceFile, string destFile)
        {
            try
            {
                var ServerReportFTP = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerReportFTP"];
                var ServerReportFTPUserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerReportFTPUserName"];
                var ServerReportFTPPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerReportFTPPassword"];

                var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerReportFTP);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ServerReportFTPUserName, ServerReportFTPPassword);

                var sourceStream = new StreamReader(sourceFile);
                var fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
                sourceStream.Close();
                request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

                var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
                requestStream.Close();

                //var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                //response.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }
```